# How to set parent id when using nested attributes form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2 webapp. In this app I am using the gem Act_as_tenant.
I also got accounts (tenants) that has many users (trough a join table).

I am creating both the account and the first user using nested attributes.
The user model got an attribute called account_id which I need to fill with the created account. Both the account and the user is created successfully BUT the id of the newly created account is not set in the users model (account_id). How can I make sure it is?